# Delete multiple entries from table without having ID

Tags: mysql, sql, database, csv

I imported this database from multiple CSV files to column name has to be maintained and from more CSV files still to be uploaded so cannot add an unique ID.

Query should be like this:

```
    delete from table1
    USING table1, table1 as vtable
    WHERE (NOT table1.ID=vtable.ID)
    AND (table1.field_name=vtable.field_name)
```

If I write a query like this everything will be deleted:

```
    delete from table1
    USING table1, table1 as vtable
    WHERE
    AND (table1.field_name1=vtable.field_name1) AND (table1.field_name2=vtable.field_name2)
    AND (table1.field_name3=vtable.field_name3) AND (table1.field_name4=vtable.field_name4)
```

Please help me find solution to delete from table where field name1,2,3,4 are same without any distinct ID.

Comment: well if you dont have a Unique id for each record how can you determine if two records are the same or different? Your queries don't make any sense at all! Isn't vtable an alias for table1? you are referring to the same column in both queries. Why can't have a auto increment id for each record added to the table?

Comment: I imported this database from multiple CSV files to column name has to be maintained and from more CSV files still to be uploaded so cannot add an unique ID

Comment: I wasnt suggesting to change column names you can simply add a PK column to your table. what if two CSV files contain the same record? which I think is the problem you trying to solve here. if you want to do this without a Unique ID you have to think about a criteria that determines two records are the same or not (aka, you need to compare values of columns that determines if two record in the table are the same or some how comparable) you can't delete based on column name.

Comment: is it possible to add a column(i.e unique id) and then add CSV file..because the column will change will csv file able to map columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can add an unique key on product name.

```
ALTER IGNORE IGNORE table_name
ADD UNIQUE KEY pdt_name(field_name);
```

On this alter, it will remove the duplicates. Thereafter, you can do `INSERT IGNORE` or `LOAD DATA .. IGNORE`